# Create file event to the SAS batch

Tags: file, sas

I need to create new file event to the SAS batch, which will check if nightly batch has finished working and after it my SAS job will run. 
To do that i am checking table:

```
select * from table where date=sysdate
```

And if it has record that means that nightly batch is finished running.

Has anybody any idea how to create file event with this condition?

Comment: it's a blatant product recommendation on my side, but you could try out https://sas9api.io - it lets you do exactly that using any tool you like

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are meaning selective structure:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select * from table where date=sysdate;
quit;

%if &sysnobs %then %do;
    my sas job...
%end;
```